# How make browser update script file when manifest updates but allow caching?

Tags: javascript, html, apache, caching, html5-appcache

I have tried two different ways and both do not work:

**1. Update the manifest so browser sees there's changes and updates**

This updates all files except JavaScript files. The browser sees there's a difference, downloads everything (including JavaScript files) but uses the cached version of the JavaScript files.

**2. Send no-cache headers (see code below) to stop caching of script files**

This causes the browser to throw an error and no longer cache anything. It says an ApplicationCache error occurred.

The no-cache code:

```
<filesMatch "\.(js)$">
    FileETag None
    <ifModule mod_headers.c>
        Header unset ETag
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
    </ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

The above makes all browsers *not* cache the app for offline use.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: First note, the application cache seems to be deprecated (but still the only solution): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache

How do you know that the browser downloads the scripts? I find it hard to believe it loads successfully but does not use it. It might give a "304 - Not modified" status.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have sufficient perspective to say whether or not this is a *best practice*, but whenever our team makes Javascript changes, we increment a query string variable at the end of the path.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/script.js?v=10"></script>
```

Note the **v=10** at the end of the src attribute. This implies to the browser that a different file is being retrieved, and therefore, circumvents the cache.

I picked up this method by following existing practice of co-workers.

Comment: That's not a bad solution, and I'd have it automatically update the manifest as well (because it has to match in the manifest)